# Visual studio code intellisense stopped working, no more css tab options, or color pickers

Tags: visual-studio-code

I noticed that all of the sudden the intellisense for css stopped working, I can't autocomplete anything anymore. what I do notice is that when I am using tailwind everything intellisense related works even the colour picker. any idea how to fix this? already repaired via the installer but doesn't work

Comment: Could an update to an extension be to blame?

Comment: Are you using built-in intellisense?